# Xcode setting text on a label causes button functionality to not work

Tags: xcode

I have one label and one button on my app. Whenever the button is pressed, The label should update according to the number of times it has been pressed and the button should change its location on the screen.

Both parts work individually, but when I try to have both parts work at the same time, the label updates correctly, but the button does not change from its original location.

```
@IBOutlet weak var score: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!
private var points:Int = 0

@IBAction func changeXY(_ sender: Any) {

    let buttonWidth = button.bounds.width / 2.0

    let randomX:CGFloat = CGFloat.random(in: (buttonWidth + minX)...(maxX - buttonWidth))
    let randomY:CGFloat = CGFloat.random(in: (minY + buttonWidth)...(maxY - buttonWidth))

    button.center = .init(x: randomX, y: randomY)
    points = points + 1
    score.text = "Score: \(points)"
}
```

Commenting out `points = points + 1` OR changing `score.text = "Score: \(points)"` to a string that does not involve `points` allows the button to change position slightly as intended (it does not change on the first button press, but works as intended after the first press). Commenting both parts out makes the button reposition completely as intended.

I have no idea why this is since it seems like the label and button's functionality are completely separate from each other.

I have no idea if it matters but in my `viewDidLoad()` I overrided this method `viewSafeAreaInsetsDidChange()` and did call `super` in the one I overrided.

Thanks

Comment: button is positioned by constraints, u have to update them. set translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;

Comment: Or maybe try the opposite: remove all constraints from the button so that its position will not change when the view layout  changes (which happens when you  change the label content).